# How to fit my SVG Image to the Parent wrapper div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following code snippet that I am working with. I could not get my SVG image fit my container div.

```css
.img {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://svgur.com/i/SPb.svg" alt="An svg image">
</div>
```

My Codepen:
[https://codepen.io/huyct1996/pen/zYKwXjM](http://Codepen)

Any help would be highly regarded. Thank you

Comment: Please include code here that you are having issues with and specifics of what the problem you are having is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your svg file, so that text inside of it is centered, rather then translated.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="400" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="112" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="336" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="56" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="280" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="224" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="168" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <rect y="392" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
    <text fill="#8B90A0" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Drop it here or add a file</text>
</svg>
```

It will not expand vertically. Y attributes are numbers not percentages

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was a solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Just use `width:100%; height:100%` in the CSS. It will force the `SVG` to take up all the space of the `div`.

```
<div class="img">
  <img style="width:100%; height: 100%;" src="img.svg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried but the content in svg "drop it here" doesn't resize by div

Comment: @HuyNguyễn what is that?

Comment: When do I add "style =" width: 100%; height: 100%; "on it still doesn't work, do you go to the codepen to help me out? Thank you very much

Comment: @HuyNguyễn Hey Nguyen, u are right. I tried it, but height is not 500px, it is more than that. 544px. Let us see. If I can find something

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Thank you, I am a novice so looking forward to your help

Comment: No problem dear friend. I will see what to do with this. And come up with the solution hopefully... InshaAllah :) It seems you have update codepen. let me see

Comment: Have also edited your question for better readability. Enjoy coding dear. Need any help, let me know :) Good Bye

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is solved with `object-fit:contain`: Try below code:

**UPDATE:** SVG itself has some issues, so I directly put the SVG in HTML to show you the right way of doing it:

```css
 .img-wrapper {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
      }

      img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <!-- <img
        src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huyct1996/images/3ddca45402fbc1ce4ee0f1a58f67a34f87f2d8aa/empty.svg"
        alt="An SVG Image"
      /> -->

      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        fill="none"
      >
        <rect width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="112" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="336" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="56" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="280" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="224" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="168" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <rect y="392" width="100%" height="1" fill="#ECEEF4" />
        <text
          fill="#8B90A0"
          x="50%"
          y="50%"
          dominant-baseline="middle"
          text-anchor="middle"
        >
          Drop it here or add a file
        </text>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use this photo (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huyct1996/images/3ddca45402fbc1ce4ee0f1a58f67a34f87f2d8aa/empty.svg) when minimizing the screen will lose the words "Drop here ...", is there a way for SVG images instead Change according to when responsive? Thank you !!

Comment: hmmm. OKKK, let me check your images first :) My friend !!! You know what coders are awesome... Just being humourous ...

Comment: You really are a kind person

Comment: Oh Dear ! That's your kindness, seeing kindness in other's. :) OK, The thing with our SVG image is that, if you open the SVG code, by directly pasting the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huyct1996/images/3ddca45402fbc1ce4ee0f1a58f67a34f87f2d8aa/empty.svg in the browser and doing CTRL + SHIFT+I, THen svg has itself issues. You can modify that :)

Comment: I have found a solution to the question, thank you for your help and helpful contributions to me and others.

Comment: Very Nice, Mate. You are welcome. Happy coding fellow :)